# How to figure out the direction of current and polarity of a circuit element?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, homework, polarity

How do I determine the direction of current in the boxed region? Also, how do I figure out the polarity of the resistor?[image]

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Comment: @winny Hi there! No, it isn't. I have a test coming up in a few days and found this problem a little difficult to attempt.

Comment: That’s effectively homework. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: There is literally nothing more than looking at the battery connected to it. Also the numbers do not add up so the problem either has a typo or is otherwise unsolvable.

Comment: @Justme What if I replace the battery over there with an inductor while maintain the same current through that branch? And, yes, I noticed too that the numbers don't add up. I made up these values without checking through. Apogees for that.

Comment: @winny I understood how to determine the current and its direction using KCL. But, I'm not sure how to confirm whether the Passive Sign Convention I assumed is right or wrong for the resistor.

Comment: @SathvikR. If you change a battery (which one?) to an inductor, then it's a different circuit and the question is about this circuit.

Comment: I have honestly not heard the term passive sign convention. If you replace the batteries with voltage sources, does it become easier?

Comment: @Justme Say the 8V battery is replaced with the inductor, then how would you determine the polarity? I'm trying to figure out if there is any general method to figure the polarity.

Comment: @SathvikR. Then draw an inductor there. Ask yourself how inductor behaves in a DC circuit and act accordingly. Look at the remaining voltage and current sources.

Comment: @winny I'm genuinely confused now. Could you please explain your method for figuring out the polarity of the resistor?

Comment: The polarity will come from your KVL and KCL analysis. I'm asking if the batteries are causing you any confusion? If yes, would ideal voltage sources make your problem easier to digest? If no, keep the batteries and perform KCL and KVL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use KCL to find the direction and magnitude of the current by inspection, then use Ohm's law and the Passive Sign Convention to find the direction of the voltage across the resistor.

Since this looks like homework I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but would you mind explaining what 'Passive Sign Convention' is?

Comment: I can't explain it any better than Wikipedia does.

Answer (score 0):

Use mesh or nodal analysis. If the current found in a direction of a branch is negative, then its direction is opposite. There is no way to tell which direction current would flow in some cases. Just follow a convention like current would flow clockwise in each mesh if you use mesh analysis. If you obtain negative current, then it flows the other way.

In Nodal analysis you use a central node to write nodal equation. After you calculate current in a branch assuming one direction, if its negative, then its direction is opposite. Refer a book on circuit analysis for detailed explanation.

Always stick to a convention and depending on values of current you get, decide on its direction.

Answer (score 0):

> *How do I determine the direction of current in the boxed region?*

Quite simply, there is an 8 volt source across a 3 Ω load so, the current is 2.667 amps and flows from the positive terminal of the 8 volt battery and upwards through the 3 Ω resistor.

<sub>The current source and the 12 volt battery play no role in creating current in the 3 Ω resistor.</sub>

Comment: Why do the current source and the 12 volt battery play no role in creating the current? I mean they are in the circuit, so there must be some effect, right?

Comment: The current they produce only flows into the 8 volt source. Only the 8 volt source dictates the voltage across the 3 ohm resistor hence, its current is 2.667 amps. It's simple ohm's law.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There is a path for the current to enter the resistor branch right? I'm sorry if I'm annoying you but I would really appreciate it it if you could elaborate more.

Comment: **All** the current from the 12 volt battery in series with the 4 amp current source flows into the 8 volt battery. By Ohm's law there is 8 volts across a 3 ohm resistor hence, the current in the 3 ohm resistor must be 2.667 amps. There is no potential path for current from the 12 volt battery in series with the 4 amp current source to enter the 3 ohm resistor **EXCEPT WHEN** the 8 volt source is **not ideal**. But, in your circuit, the 8 volt source **is ideal** i.e. it has no series resistance implied; it maintains 8 volts across its terminals even if a million amps is flowing into it.